# How to prevent open last projects when IntelliJ IDEA starts?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

By default IntelliJ IDEA opens the last project when starting.

How to start IntelliJ without opening last project?

Comment: Whoever decided this setting needs to be enabled by default clearly has never worked in a codebase where you need to have ~10-15 projects open regularly. I used to lose ~5 minutes of my life waiting for Intellij to reload projects that I didn't need open every time I restarted it. Thank god there's a way to turn that off!

Comment: Strange how the default for IntelliJ/Rider are different.

Answer (score 513, accepted):

IntelliJ 14, 15, 16:

```
Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Reopen last project on startup
```

Previously:

```
Settings -> General -> Startup/shutdown -> Reopen last project on startup.
```

Comment: In 14 this is now in _Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings_. Or you can use the search functionality to find it easier.

Comment: Settings is also renamed as Preferences under Intellij IDEA tab.

Comment: Also works for other IDE's from JetBrains such as CLion.

Comment: Just search "System Settings" in the search panel.

Comment: Is there a way to do it from the Toolbox, that would set it up for all IDEs?

Comment: Thanks, and there is a slight difference in IntelliJ 2021.2.1 (but I don't know when it changed), this is now "Reopen projects on startup"

Comment: I work with microservices and sometimes I just open IntelliJ and it spawns 15 windows slowing down everything, I'd like it only opens the latest project as visual studio code can be set. In the while, I'll settle with no window at all

Comment: IntelliJ's settings menu is unbelievably poorly designed; SO is the only way I can find anything. What settings don't affect Appearance and Behaviour? What determines what is an Advanced Setting?

Answer (score 198):

If for any reason you need to change this setting without using the UI (for example if IDEA is hanging when it opens your project), you can find the setting in eg

```
/.IntelliJIdea10/config/options/ide.general.xml
```

The location of the file is documented in http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181

The specific setting you need to change (or add) is

```
<application>
  <component name="GeneralSettings">
    <option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
  </component>
</application>
```

### Mac

In the latest version of IntelliJ, the location of this file on a Mac is

```
~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.2/options/ide.general.xml
```

### Settings Repository

If you have the settings repository enabled, then it can be found here:

~/.IntelliJIdea${idea_version}/config/settingsRepository/repository/ide.general.xml

Comment: Updated documentation available here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108

Comment: OSX: __sed -i.bak 's/"reopenLastProject" value="true"/"reopenLastProject" value="false"/' ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/options/ide.general.xml__

Comment: On windows 7: After editing you should have:<application>
  <component name="GeneralSettings">
    <option name="confirmExit" value="false" />
    <option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
    <option name="showTipsOnStartup" value="false" />
  </component>
  <component name="Registry">
    <entry key="ide.firstStartup" value="false" />
  </component>
</application>

Comment: On Mac, path should be something like this for 2017 and onward: `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2017.2/options/ide.general.xml`

Comment: Add the line if missing: `<option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />`

Comment: In IntelliJ 17, when I needed to stop projects from reopening at startup, editing the `<option name="openPaths">` tag in the file `recentProjects.xml` worked for me.

Comment: In Idea 2020.1, the path was hanged to ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/options/ide.general.xml

Comment: There is also a command line option `dontReopenProjects`: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#arguments

Comment: In 2022/23, MacOS: `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.3/options/ide.general.xml`

Answer (score 22):

If you're just trying to start up IntelliJ once without opening any previous projects (eg due to IntelliJ crashing with a specific project), you can use the `dontReopenProjects` option from the command line.

Example:

```
C:\dev\ide\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\bin\idea64.exe dontReopenProjects
```

Note: There are also a bunch of other useful command line options you can use, such as `noSplash` and `disableNonBundledPlugins`.

---

Source CLI documentation (credit to mikebridge for pointing it out in a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8143981/6854489)): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#arguments

Answer (score 19):

The fastest way is to

> ctrl+shift+a (windows)
>
> cmd+shift+a (mac)

and then just type

> reopen last project on startup

[image]

Comment: Hallelujah! thank you very much

Answer (score 14):

On the Mac the file is located at `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/options/ide.general.xml`

And then set the `reopenLastProject` option to `false`.

Answer (score 14):

For Intellij 13 on Mac 10.9 (Mavericks), it is located at ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/options/ide.general.xml as well.  ( I don't have enough reputation to vote up Nicholas' answer ).

Answer (score 12):

IntelliJ 2016.x keeps this information in its own file now.
On my MacBook Pro w/OSX:

```
~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.2/options/recentProjects.xml
```

If IntelliJ hangs on startup, force quit the app then rename this file to something like "recentProjects.xml.bak."

Upon restart you'll get the option screen for creating or opening a project.

Note: the actual path may vary depending upon which version of IntelliJ you have installed eg.

`IntelliJIdea2016.1/  IntelliJIdea2016.2/  IntelliJIdea2016.3/`

Comment: You can also just go remove all mentions of the project giving you problems from this file and keep the rest of your recent settings intact.

Comment: it's better to remove the lines under `<option name="openPaths">` tag that you want to prevent from opening on launch

Answer (score 9):

Just tick the checkbox:

```
Settings -> General -> Reopen last project on startup
```

This is for idea 10.

Answer (score 9):

I opened this file in VI using this path:

~/Library/preferences/IdeaIC13/options/ide.general.xml

and changed this value:

```
<option name="reopenLastProject" value="true" />
```

to

```
<option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 9):

For new IntelliJ versions [like 2020.3.2 ...]

[image]

Comment: For anyone who needs the `ide.general.xml` file for this version, it has been moved to `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/options/ide.general.xml`. You may need to manually add the `<option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />` line to the GeneralSettings block.

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ 14 it is:

> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Startup/Shutdown -> 
>   Reopen last project on startup

You can bring the settings window by pressing CTL+ALT+S.

Answer (score 6):

**Intellij Idea** or **Android Studio**:

From the menu go to :

`File` > `Settings >Appearence & Behavior` > `System Settings`.

disable the option:

**`Reopen last project on startup`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

On `WINDOWS`, the path is:

`C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.IntelliJIdea[VERSION]\config\options\ide.general.xml`

Then set `reopenLastProject` to `false`, i.e.:

`<application>
  <component name="GeneralSettings">
    <option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
  </component>
</application>`

---

PS: You may have to create the option if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Since 2020.1 WebStorm settings are located here: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\WebStorm[VERSION]\options\ide.general.xml

Answer (score 0):

For The latest version of Android Studio IDE

Just follow this steps

File > Settings > System Settings > click Reopen the last project Check-box > Apply or Okay

Answer (score 0):

To manage this setting through the config file in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 Community Edition, head to `~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC2019.1/options/` to use Patrick Wilkes' answer with the ide.general.xml edit.