# How can I prevent IntelliJ from opening up every project when I open it?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using intellij 11 CE on OS X lion. If I have 5 projects open when I quit intellij, then it opens all of them up when I open intellij. I want it to open none of them and then I can just select which to open from "recent projects". How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent open last projects when intellij idea start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362036/how-to-prevent-open-last-projects-when-intellij-idea-start)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there's a checkbox in settings > General for "reopen last project on startup"