# Android Studio 3 Desktop-Run does not show app-window

Tags: android-studio

I've just updated from Android Studio Version 2 to 3.

Now when I run my desktop configuration the app-window does not
appear anymore.

It is visible in the taskbar though and when I hover over the taskbar-icon I can see a litte preview of the app. I tried moving the window with Windows+Arrow-Keys, but no success.

The app is running properly from what I can see in the logs.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I figured out a way to get the window on the screen:
I have to hover over the taskbar-icon till the preview pops up, then right
click on the preview and choose 'move'. After that I have to press any arrow key to make the window stick to my mouse.

It seems the window is somehow beyond the lower right corner of my screen. I have to repeat this everytime I run the app again.

Another problem I've noticed: The window size isnt recognized properly. I have a screen resolution of 3840x 2160. When I maximize the window my app says it is only 1536x801. I didn't have these problems with Android Studio 2

Comment: Thanks sir, that last update saved my life! Worked fine!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This happened to me with other apps too (Flipper) and AS version 4.0

Comment: From Update: I had to hover over the taskbar-icon till the preview pops up, then right-click on the preview and choose 'maximize. Then I could see the window.
Update text helped. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know who you're, but I will find you, and thank you for saving my live <3

Answer (score 28):

Click on Android Studio button on Taskbar. If Android Studio do not show, hit Alt+Space and click Maximize

Answer (score 8):

This happens to me whenever I use was previously using Android Studio on a external display. It opens and places itself where the connected display "was". I was able to figure out how to get the window to show by following Draz's answer

> I have to hover over the taskbar-icon till the preview pops up, then right click on the preview and choose 'move'

But instead of move I click "maximize" and it fills my laptops screen.

Comment: this is what helped me. Should be the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be happening in ver 4.1.1 on Windows 10 and as noted [here with prior versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362036/how-to-prevent-open-last-projects-when-intellij-idea-starts/8143981#8143981), you need to set "**reopenLastProject**" to false in the **ide.general.xml** file. That settings file for version 4.1.1 is located in

> **\Users\*USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\options**

.

Then you may have to click **Settings->Restore Default Settings** from the opening dialog.
[image]

Comment: My studio upgraded from 2.x to 4.1.1 and after then studio never launched. After remove whole directory "\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Google\", now I can use studio with cleared state.

Answer (score 3):

After following the steps above and restoring the window, cleaning the project then saving it would prevent the problem from happening on the next launch!

Answer (score 0):

Use this steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8143981/4024146 to set: **Reopen last project on startup** to false in XML file

- open another project.
- file > open recent
- same window

This helps me for Android studio 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I use Lenovo carbon, and things of this sort happen often. Too often.
I've tried multiple solutions and depending on a day either one of these two fix this issue for me:

1. running Android Studio as administrator
2. restarting PC completely